# Combining two mySQL tables sum() doesn't return entries that are zero or null

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Locations and inventory

Locations:

```
locationID | locationName |
----------------------------
     1     |     place1
     2     |     place2
     3     |     place3
```

inventory

```
locationID | itemID | total
-------------------------------
     1     |    a   |    6
     1     |    b   |    2
     2     |    a   |    1
```

I then have a query something like this:

```
Select locationID, sum(total) as totalItemCount FROM Locations, inventory GROUPBY locationID
```

This would return results like this:

```
    locationID | totalItemCount
   -------------------------
        1      |      8
        2      |      1
```

Results I would like to see would have locationID 3 with either zero or null. I just need it to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm, you need a `LEFT JOIN` then like below instead of `INNER JOIN`. Also, notice that I have modified your query and used ANSI style explicit join syntax which is much better than the old style syntax which you are using currently.

```
Select l.locationID, 
sum(i.total) as totalItemCount 
FROM Locations l
LEFT JOIN inventory i ON l.locationID = i.locationID
GROUP BY l.locationID;
```